# Email Hyperlink with parameters is being made lowercase when consumed by Angular site (Query String)

Tags: angular, .net-core, token, query-string

Good day.

I have a project that uses dotnetcore2 and angular.
Using builtin Core functions (UserManager) I create a token:

GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync()

then I mail the user to follow a link to reset his/her password.

The Token is sent correctly in the mail, and the hyperlink does have the token in the correct case.

When I click on the Hyperlink I am directed to the correct page, but the Query String has everything in lowercase, ie the Token is made lowercase.

Anyone have a solution for this?

1. Token sample when made in the api.
2. Token sample when sent in mail (The hyperlink in the mail)
3. Token sample in query string when page is opened by clicking on the email hyperlink

   1. "77BqHb51n2P"
   2. "77BqHb51n2P"
   3. "77bqhb51n2p"

Comment: Do you have a navigateUrl in the method that sends the email?

Comment: Hi, no I build the link in the body of the mail:
`"please follow this <a href=" + Url + "?token=" + token>link</a>."`

Hi, the link url is:
`"http://localhost:77777/resetaccount?token=77BqHb5"`

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem:

in App.Component.ts

Comment out this:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        let url = (<NavigationStart>event).url;

        if (url !== url.toLowerCase()) {
            this.router.navigateByUrl((<NavigationStart>event).url.toLowerCase());
        }
    }
});
```

Now I just need to make sure all my services and routes are correct because without the above casing is now an issue everywhere.